# Abbreviations for loss functions to be passed to model.compile()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses) describes different loss functions, but it is possible to use abbreviations instead of importing and passing the actual loss object (see an examples [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L640))

`MeanSquaredError` can be passed as the string `mse`, `MeanAbsoluteError` as `mae`. Some are obvious like that, but what about other losses like `CategoricalCrossentropy`, `CosineSimilarity`, or `Hinge`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some loss functions and their string aliases (All of them can be imported from `tf.keras.losses`):

| Class Name | String Alias(es) |
| --- | --- |
| MeanSquaredError() | `mean_squared_error`, `mse`, `MSE` |
| MeanAbsoluteError() | `mean_absolute_error`, `mae`, `MAE` |
| MeanAbsolutePercentageError() | `mean_absolute_percentage_error`, `mape`, `MAPE` |
| MeanSquaredLogarithmicError() | `mean_squared_logarithmic_error`, `msle`, `MSLE` |
| KLDivergence() | `kl_divergence`, `kullback_leibler_divergence`, `kld`, `KLD` |
| Hinge() | `hinge` |
| CosineSimilarity() | `cosine_similarity` |
| LogCosh() | `log_cosh`, `logcosh` |
| CategoricalCrossentropy() | `categorical_crossentropy` |
| SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() | `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` |
| BinaryCrossentropy() | `binary_crossentropy` |

As you can see, some of them have more than one string alias, whereas mostly have one alias.

Reference: [Source code of keras.losses](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you